# display string and integer in a bracket in textview

Tags: android, textview, string.xml

I have tried

```
String name = mContext.getString(R.string.product_and_quantity, banner.getProduct_name().trim(), banner.getProduct_quantity());
```

and in String.xml file

```
 <string name="product_and_quantity">%1$s x(%2$d)</string>
```

but still I am not getting proper view in some items as shown in image.

I tried this too

```
 String name=banner.getProduct_name().trim()+"x("+ banner.getProduct_quantity()+")";
       SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder=new SpannableStringBuilder();
       spannableStringBuilder.append(banner.getProduct_name().trim());
       spannableStringBuilder.append(" X(");

       spannableStringBuilder.append(Integer.toString(banner.getProduct_quantity()));
       spannableStringBuilder.append(mContext.getString(R.string.closing_bracket));
```

and string.xml file has

```
 <string name="closing_bracket">)</string>
but still i am getting the same error. 
I have invested 3-4 hours on stackoverflow about this error but no solution. Please help.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the text is too long and breaks into 3 lines and only the first two are shown. Like this:

```
Tandori
Sauce Pasta
(1)
```

And the textview is limited in height and only shows the first two lines.

**EDIT**

Based on the provided layout xml and discussion in comments, the solution was, to change the textview's height to match_parent.

Comment: when i hard code it . it shows properly.  I have not added any line breaks. 
in logcat it is shown as `2020-09-02 10:14:22.075 16135-16135/com.bunny.burgersmore I/ListItemsAdapterAdmin: onBindViewHolder: Tandoori Sauce Pasta X(1)`

Comment: `<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtItemName"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:text="Tandoori Sauce Pasta X(1)"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                  ></androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView>`
this is the textview code

Comment: If its showing correctly in Logcat, then its definitely that the TextView is not high enough. Change layout_height to 200dp or something and you'll see.

Comment: yes it worked when I did match_parent. Thanks for support. Kindly edit the answer so I can upvote it